# mvn gcloud:deploy [Error gcloud app command exit code is: 2]

Tags: google-app-engine

I am getting the following exception while trying to deploy an app on appengine

mvn gcloud:deploy [Error gcloud app command exit code is: 2]

what does exit code 2 means here?

Stack trace

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:gcloud-maven-plugin:2.0.9.121.v20160815:deploy (default-cli) on project userprofilev2: Error: gcloud app command exit code is: 2 -> [Help 1]
```

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:gcloud-maven-plugin:2.0.9.121.
v20160815:deploy (default-cli) on project userprofilev2: Error: gcloud app command exit code is: 2
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error: gcloud app command exit code is: 2
        at com.google.appengine.gcloudapp.AbstractGcloudMojo.startCommand(AbstractGcloudMojo.java:463)
        at com.google.appengine.gcloudapp.GCloudAppDeploy.execute(GCloudAppDeploy.java:43)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upgrading gcloud version using 'gcloud components update' commmand, fixed my problem